# TypeError using dictionary for math in a FOR loop -- But why?

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror, mathematical-expressions

So, the intent here is to evaluate a long series of equations that change as a function of height, and finally combine them at the very end. The end goal is to approximate an integration w/ respect to height (that part is still in the works). Right now, I just need to make the last equation here work.

I'm getting "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'", in reference to attempting to evaluate "a5" as the final step here.  I can only assume that this is an issue with iterating through the dictionary d_gamox (which is a series of int:float pairs), but having done something similar elsewhere with no issue, I'm totally baffled. Maybe I've just been staring at this code so long I'm missing something obvious, so what do you guys think?

(Also I'm sure this code is a mess, but rn it just needs to work...)

```
import numpy as np
from math import exp, sin, cos, sqrt


theta = 1 #Elevation angle in degrees
f = 1000 #Frequency in MHz
r = 200 #Range to target in km
h_ant = 100 #Height of antenna + terrain in m

###############

#Constants
r_0 = 6370 #radius of Earth in km
T_0 = 300 #Sea-level temp in K
P_0 = 1013.25 #Sea-level pressure in mbar
N_s = 313 #Avg sea-level refractivity
C_e = 0.1439  #constant for refractivity
C = 2.0058 #for Gam_ox

alpha = 5.2561222 #constants for pressure
beta = 0.034164794
gamma = 11.388265

f_r = 22.235 #for water vapor

rad = np.radians(theta) #Elevation angle in rad
r_m = r * 1000 #Range in meters
f_GHz = f / 1000 #Frequency in GHz
h_ant_km = h_ant/1000 #Antenna height in km
n_0 = 1 + (N_s / (10**6)) #Refractive index

###############

d_gamox = {}
d_fNp = {
    1 : 56.2648,
    3 : 58.4466,
    5 : 59.5910,
    7 : 60.4348,
    9 : 61.1506,
    11 : 61.8002,
    13 : 62.4112,
    15 : 62.9980,
    17 : 63.5685,
    19 : 64.1272,
    21 : 64.6779,
    23 : 65.2240,
    25 : 65.7626,
    27 : 66.2978,
    29 : 66.8313,
    31 : 67.3627,
    33 : 67.8923,
    35 : 68.4205,
    37 : 68.9478,
    39 : 69.4741,
    41 : 70,
    43 : 70.5249,
    45 : 71.0497
    }

d_fNm = {
    1 : 118.7505,
    3 : 62.4863,
    5 : 60.3061,
    7 : 59.1642,
    9 : 58.3239,
    11 : 57.6125,
    13 : 56.9682,
    15 : 56.3634,
    17 : 55.7839,
    19 : 55.2214,
    21 : 54.6728,
    23 : 54.1294,
    25 : 53.5960,
    27 : 53.0695,
    29 : 52.5458,
    31 : 52.0259,
    33 : 51.5091,
    35 : 50.9949,
    37 : 50.4830,
    39 : 49.9730,
    41 : 49.4648,
    43 : 48.9582,
    45 : 48.4530
    }

d1 = {
      0 : 5.947, 
      2 : 2.946, 
      4 : 1.074, 
      6 : 0.3779, 
      8 : 0.1172, 
      10 : 0.01834, 
      12 : 0.003708, 
      14 : 0.0008413, 
      16 : 0.0006138, 
      18 : 0.0004449, 
      20 : 0.0004490, 
      22 : 0.0005230, 
      24 : 0.0006138, 
      26 : 0.0007191, 
      28 : 0.0005230, 
      30 : 0.0003778, 
      32 : 0.0002710
      }
uNp = list()
uNm = list()
uN0 = list()
for i , j in d_fNp.items():
    Np = (i*(2*i+3))/(i+1)
    Nm = (i+1)*(2*i-1)/i
    N0 = (2*(i**2+i+1)*(2*i+1))/(i*(i+1))    
    uNp.append(Np)
    uNm.append(Nm)
    uN0.append(N0)


T_h = r_m*sin(rad)+(r_m*cos(rad))**2/(2*((4/3)*(r_0*1000))) #Height of target using 4/3 Earth radius

def target_height(T_h):
    if T_h > 47000:
        return 47000 / 1000
    else:
        return T_h / 1000

h = target_height(T_h) + h_ant/1000 # Target height in km

for h1 in np.linspace(h_ant_km,h,400):


    geo_h = (r_0 * h1) / (r_0 + h1) # Geopotential height

    def T(geo_h):
        if geo_h*1000 <= 11000:
            return 288.16 - 0.0065*(geo_h*1000)
        elif geo_h*1000 > 11000 and geo_h*1000 <= 25000:
            return 216.66
        else:
            return 216.66 + 0.003*((geo_h*1000) - 25000)


    def P(geo_h):
        if geo_h*1000 <= 11000:
            return 1013.25*(T(geo_h)/288.16)**alpha
        elif geo_h*1000 > 11000 and geo_h*1000 <= 25000:
            return 226.32*exp((-beta/T(geo_h))*((geo_h*1000) - 11000))
        else:
            return 24.886*(216.66/T(geo_h))**gamma


    def n_h(h1):
        return 1 + (n_0-1)*exp(-C_e*h1) #Refractive index


    def g_h(h1):
        if h1 >= 0 and h1 <= 8:
            return 0.640
        elif h1 > 8 and h1 <= 25:
            return 0.640 + 0.04218*(h-8)
        else:
            return 1.357

    def del_f(g_h,P,T):
        return g_h(h1) * (P(geo_h)/P_0)*(T_0/T(geo_h)) #Line-breadth constant

    #Calculate FN+/-
    FNp = list()
    FNm = list()
    for i , j in d_fNp.items():
        a1 = (del_f(g_h,P,T) / ((j - f_GHz)**2 + (del_f(g_h,P,T))**2)) + (del_f(g_h,P,T) / ((j + f_GHz)**2 + (del_f(g_h,P,T))**2))
        FNp.append(a1)
    for i , j in d_fNm.items():
        b1 = (del_f(g_h,P,T) / ((j - f_GHz)**2 + (del_f(g_h,P,T))**2)) + (del_f(g_h,P,T) / ((j + f_GHz)**2 + (del_f(g_h,P,T))**2))
        FNm.append(b1)

    def F_0(del_f):
        return del_f(g_h,P,T)/(f_GHz**2+(del_f(g_h,P,T))**2) #Non-resonant component

    #Calculate A_N

    x = np.multiply(FNp, uNp)
    y = np.multiply(FNm, uNm)
    z = list()
    for i in uN0:
        x1 = i*F_0(del_f)
        z.append(x1)

    Enk = list()
    for i, j in d_fNp.items():
        x2 = 2.06844*i*(i+1)
        Enk.append(x2)

    a2 = np.add(x, y)
    a3 = np.add(a2,z)
    a4 = list()
    for i in Enk:
        b2 = exp(-i/T(geo_h))
        a4.append(b2)

    A_N = np.multiply(a3,a4)

    def gam_ox(P,T,A_N):
        return C * P(geo_h) * (T(geo_h)**-3)*(f_GHz**2)*(sum(A_N))
    d_gamox[h1] = [gam_ox(P,T,A_N)]

intlist = list()
for i, j in d_gamox.items():
    a5 = ((1 + (n_0 - 1) * exp(-C_e * i)) * j) / sqrt(1 - ((n_0 * cos(rad)) / ((1 + (n_0 - 1) * exp(-C_e * i)) * (1 + i / r_0)))**2)
    intlist.append(a5)
I1 = sum(intlist)

print(I1)
```

Comment: can you add an example of what `d_gamox` is?

Comment: In order to increase the possibility someone will help you, it would be useful if you post the input, the code, the desired output and the error you get from the interpreter.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error using a range of possible inputs. I think we really need to see the real inputs please. The real values of `n_0`, `C_e`, `rad`, `r_0`, and a minimal sample of `d_gamox` would be required.

Comment: Somewhere you have a variable containing a list that you are multiplying. I couldn't see where as you didn't include the full code or the full traceback.

Comment: To localize this one could use a `assert not isinstance(name, list)` statement with `name` replaced by each of the potential variables before the point of the error. Or use the debugger and print the local variables when the error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happens in this line:

```
a5 = ((1 + (n_0 - 1) * exp(-C_e * i)) * j) / sqrt(1 - ((n_0 * cos(rad)) / ((1 + (n_0 - 1) * exp(-C_e * i)) * (1 + i / r_0)))**2)
```

The error message means that you have a sequence amongst your factors, which can't me multiplied by non-ints. In this case, it is `j`, which is a list of one element: `[0.005631212879043453]`. If you specify `j[0]` to access the float inside the list instead of `j`, it works.

Comment: If I `print(d_gamox)`, though, there are as many values as keys, ie. 400. I'm not sure where the one element list you mentioned comes from.

Comment: I printed j inside the loop and it was a list. Check it with `print(type(j))`. The `d_gamox`'s values' type seems to be a list.

Comment: If you print `d_gamox`, you can see that the float numbers are inside brackets. That's where the `list` type comes from. Does the fix work for you?

Comment: Okay, I see. The example I used to figure out how to create a dictionary via a loop had a typo that I didn't notice that made the values individual lists, and I just copied it right into my own code. Whoops. Changing how `d_gamox` was created fixed it. Thanks a bunch!!